# How to use FParsec to parse identifiers with different start and end characters

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm having difficulty working out the best way to parse identifiers that have different characters at the start and end. For example, let's say that the start characters of our identifiers may be upper and lowercase only, while the middle of an identifier may also include digits and colons. The end of an identifier may not be a colon, but may be an apostrophe.

So the following are all legal identifiers:

```
f, f0, f:', f000:sdfsd:asdf
```

But the following are not:

```
0, hello:, he'llo
```

I can't see how best to handle the backtracking: a colon is fine in the middle, but we need some lookahead to determine whether we are at the end of the identifier.

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions. Using a regex is a pragmatic approach, but I find it slightly disappointing that there doesn't seem to be clean/obvious way of doing this otherwise.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be much easier for others to solve specific problem instead of asking them to write code for you.

Comment: This sounds like a job for regex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think you should use regex, however I came up with a different pattern:

```
let pattern = regex @"^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9:]*[a-zA-Z']?)$"
```

which will hold all of your wanted Matches in the first group.  You can use an online [RegExp tool](http://regex101.com/) to validate your matches/grouping.

Comment: This pattern seems to be too liberal, as it allows any final character. I'm also not sure what the trailing `]` is for.

Comment: Fair enough, I underspecified there. The intention was `[a-zA-Z0-9']`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with a regex parser

```
let ident = regex @"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\:]*[A-Za-z0-9\']"
```

http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to do it. Your regex is not quite right though, it rejects any single-character identifier. You need to make the whole except the initial character class optional.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you have escaped the `:` and `'` characters. Is this important?